# Does it exist an equivalent of box-sizing: border-box in flexbox for React Native?

Tags: react-native, flexbox, box-sizing

I would like the size of my boxes not to be changed by margin and padding.

Comment: Hmmm... what I've seen there's working box-sizing by default. See example at: https://rnplay.org/apps/GF43cw

Answer (score 38, accepted):

React Native styles all views as if box-sizing: `border-box` is set. See this code: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/5aa1fb3ff326a429e33a443576da866f2a63c20c/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/views/view/ReactViewBackgroundDrawable.java#L632

Comment: Although, this behaves very weird, like an `absolute` child with `width: "100%", height: "100%"` will appear after the `padding` values

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in another answer, In React Native, everything is treated as if as if `box-sizing: border-box` is set.
A workaround to simulate css `content-box` is to wrap your component in a container `View`, and add your border and padding to that `View`.

Answer (score 0):

react native don't have an  option for

```
 boxSixing: "border-box"
```

what you can do in your styling is this

```
<View style={ {
    flex: 1,
    alignContent: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
}}>
    <View style={ {
        flex: 1,
        width: "95%" // or width of the box - intended margin
    }}>
        ***chi;dren goes here***
    <View/>
<View/>
```

Any component that goes into that view will be at the center  With a margin of 5% or whats is specified, which solves the issue for now till react-native provides a better solution

Answer (score -2):

Let O (for outer) = (top, left, bottom, right) be the rectangle that represents the size
* and position of a view V. Since the box-sizing of all React Native views is border-box, any
* border of V will render inside O.

Comment: This text is copied from the link that Rashi posted above, but doesn't give any context that this quote is taken from the repo's source code. It may be better as a comment on the previous answer rather than a new one.

Answer (score -14):

you can use resizeMode: 'cover' or 'stretch' or 'contain'

Comment: What do the different options do? What does cover, vs, stretch, vs contain do? Do you have a link to the docs to show what these options mean?

Comment: Isn't that only for **images**?