# How does the React Native "box model" work?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Does React Native size components similar to the CSS `border-box` box model when specifying a height and/or width, padding and a border width?

I'm just learning RN and when trying to add a custom header to an iOS app, `<View style={{ height: 44, paddingTop: 20 }}>` doesn't seem to produce the 64pt height I'm expecting and changing to `height: 64, paddintTop: 20` gets me closer but actually seems to be bigger than the desired 64pt.

Or course, my assumption that the size is wrong is entirely empirical. I don't know how to actually measure the rendered component size to know which box model methodology is being used. And I have not run anything on device, only through the iOS simulator, I don't know if that might be causing the perceived sizing issue.

I didn't see this explained in the docs or have much luck finding an answer on the Google.

Answer (score 5):

<s>No, it seems to use the `content-box` model.</s>

<s>This doesn't seem to be documented, but if you set a width on an element and then add padding to it, you'll see the width increase.</s>

**UPDATE:** Documentation still doesn't exist as far as I can tell, but I found [a code comment here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/5aa1fb3ff326a429e33a443576da866f2a63c20c/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/views/view/ReactViewBackgroundDrawable.java#L632) (via [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38503451/does-it-exist-an-equivalent-of-box-sizing-border-box-in-flexbox-for-react-nativ#answer-47972232)) confirming that React Native indeed works off of a `border-box` model.

Comment: My issue is specific to height, I could not get height to adjust when padding is added.

Comment: @sellmeadog do you have any solution?